# I want to scroll image vertically using mouse position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been trying to modify a code which scrolls the images horizontally. I want to scroll it vertically. I don't know JQuery at all. After trying for hours I couldn't find any way to sort this thing out. Can anyone help me out in this regard.

Heres the whole code.

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    var $gal = $("#propertyThumbnails"),
      galW = $gal.outerWidth(true),
      galSW = $gal[0].scrollWidth,
      wDiff = (galSW / galW) - 1, // widths difference ratio
      mPadd = 60, // Mousemove Padding
      damp = 20, // Mousemove response softness
      mX = 0, // Real mouse position
      mX2 = 0, // Modified mouse position
      posX = 0,
      mmAA = galW - (mPadd * 2), // The mousemove available area
      mmAAr = (galW / mmAA); // get available mousemove fidderence ratio
    $gal.mousemove(function(e) {
      mX = e.pageX - $(this).parent().offset().left - this.offsetLeft;
      mX2 = Math.min(Math.max(0, mX - mPadd), mmAA) * mmAAr;
    });
    setInterval(function() {
      posX += (mX2 - posX) / damp; // zeno's paradox equation "catching delay" 
      $gal.scrollLeft(posX * wDiff);
    }, 10);
  });
});
```

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ddd;
}
#propertyThumbnails {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #444;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#propertyThumbnails img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="propertyThumbnails">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Heres the demo:

http://jsbin.com/alokat/1/edit?html,css,js,output

I changed the script as

```
$(function(){

    $(window).load(function(){

        var $gal   = $("#propertyThumbnails"),
            galW   = $gal.outerHeight(true),
            galSW  = $gal[0].scrollHeight,
            wDiff  = (galSW/galW)-1,  // widths difference ratio
            mPadd  = 60,  // Mousemove Padding
            damp   = 20,  // Mousemove response softness
            mX     = 0,   // Real mouse position
            mX2    = 0,   // Modified mouse position
            posX   = 0,
            mmAA   = galW-(mPadd*2), // The mousemove available area
            mmAAr  = (galW/mmAA);    // get available mousemove fidderence ratio

        $gal.mousemove(function(e) {
            mX = e.pageY - $(this).parent().offset().top - this.offsetTop;
            mX2 = Math.min( Math.max(0, mX-mPadd), mmAA ) * mmAAr;
        });

        setInterval(function(){
            posX += (mX2 - posX) / damp; // zeno's paradox equation "catching delay"    
            $gal.scrollTop(posX*wDiff);
        }, 10);

    });

});
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this approach but it is not consistent in webkit browsers. It works fine constantly in firefox but sometimes the image doesn't start moving at all in chrome or safari. Have you encountered this issue as well? And if so, could you please show me how you solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty head-on with your JavaScript modifications, but you also need to alter the stylesheet a bit to accomodate the new behaviour:

**CSS**

```
#propertyThumbnails img {
    display: block;
    /* ... */
}
```

[Working example on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ycx5oy4j/)

This little change will make the browser place the images *below* each other ([block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)), instead of *next* to each other ([inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente)).

Also of note the altered initialization in the JavaScript part.

Comment: That change in CSS changes the layout of images.. But images dont scroll automatically with change in mouse position

Comment: In the JSFiddle I linked they do scroll. I'm on a webkit browser, is it possible there are some inconsistenties between vendors?

Comment: Ya It does scroll.. Thanx :)

Comment: It works for multiple images..If I use only one image it doesnt scroll the window. Why so? Is it possible to make it for single image?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the direction of the scroll/overflow. Here is the change you need to make:

**CSS**

```
#propertyThumbnails {
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll; // or just overflow:auto; should also work
    background: #444;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: That change in CSS changes the layout of images.. But images dont scroll automatically with change in mouse position